# Programming Traditional Artists' Materials and Tools

Tags: colors, drawing, media, paint

Where is the Body of Knowledge for programmers interested in developing applications that simulate traditional artists' materials and tools, such as simulating natural paints?

**Is there any substantial body of knowledge or resource for software engineers interested in creating applications that reproduce the effect of painting and drawing media such as watercolor, oil, chalk, charcoal and color pencil?**

Clearly the knowledge exists and is shared by software engineers at Adobe, Corel, etc. But out here in the open, where is this information?

So far I've only come across fragmentary knowledge of a little technique here or there, but have not yet found any substantial resource. If you know where I need to look, please point me there.

Where are the best academic resources? Are there any blogs that specialize in this area? Are their organizations that specialize in this?

Comment: Links to some online SIGGRAPH papers (approved by ACM) http://trowley.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! NPR - for those of us heretofore uninitiated - refers to **Non-Photorealistic Rendering**, the "area of computer graphics that makes images
resembling traditional artistic works ([Mould](http://www.cs.usask.ca/faculty/mould/npr.html))."

[ACM Digital Library](http://libraries.acm.org/subscriptionsaccess) appears to be a very extensive source for research and academic papers on NPR. See [here](http://kesen.realtimerendering.com/npar2004Papers.htm), [here](http://kesen.realtimerendering.com/npar2006Papers.htm), and [here](http://kesen.realtimerendering.com/npar2007Papers.htm) for a good index of [NPAR](http://www.npar.org/) papers, search for 'NPR' or non-photorealistic rendering' on [this](http://trowley.org/) page.

This [page](https://portal.acm.org/purchase.cfm?id=987665&CFID=18581857&CFTOKEN=70724197) at the ACM Digital Library show an example of ways to access the material - a member (who has paid annual membership fee) can purchase the paper for $10, a non-member for $15; Alternatively, you can rent an article for such as this for $2.99 for 24 hours.

[Non-photorealistic Rendering](http://books.google.com/books?id=S4hRAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Non-photorealistic%20rendering&source=bl&ots=2NU-RrBggi&sig=0aP7uSy0XJwAsyYIucJieLZKYLs&hl=en&ei=Ea6sTbiTGZS4sQOe8JnJCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q&f=false), Bruce Gooch, Amy Gooch - 2001: A preview of this book is on Google Books and it looks like a bulls-eye for subject matter expertise.

[Non-Photorealistic Computer Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607870): Modeling, Rendering, and Animation (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Computer Graphics) by Thomas Strothotte. This book looks like a goldmine. It covers things like stippling, drawing incorrect lines, drawing artistic lines, simulating painting with wet paint, simulating pencils, strokes and textures, etc.

Microsoft and Adobe have a visible presence in this field of work, and of course employ people who are prominently involved in the NPR field, and you will see their names (or that of their employers') often appear as participants and sponsors of events like the upcoming [NPAR 2011](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/conference/cae-sbim-npar-2011/NPAR/Home) (Sponsored by adobe).

Microsoft has the impressive [Project Gustav](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gustav) ([video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=DMllkXwYXF8&feature=related)) - a software application dedicated exclusively to very realistically simulating traditional artistic tools such as paint, chalk, pencil, etc.

[Detail Preserving Paint Modeling of 3D Brushes](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=121930%20and%20video:%20youtube.com/watch?v=WFwi0qLV8hQ&feature=related).